# Can we change the cypress.env.json file name

Tags: json, typescript, testing, environment-variables, cypress

I want to use  different environment variable file for  prod environment and non prod environments. Currently I'm maintaining a single file  for all environment and going forward each env file content will be get different according the environment.  Hence is there a possibility to rename the file according the environment and pass it at run time or define the respective env file at a configuration file (cypress.json)

Sample env file names:
cypress.env.nonprod.json
cypress.env.prod.json

Answer (score 1):

You can add **scripts** into **project.json** file:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "setEnvDev": "cp cypress.env.dev.json cypress.env.json",
    "setEnvStaging": "cp cypress.env.staging.json cypress.env.json",
    "setEnvSproduction": "cp cypress.env.production.json cypress.env.json"
  }
}
```

And run

```js
$ npm run setEnvDev  
$ npx cypress run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create cypress configuration files in your project root. Like for example if you have three config files:

- production.json
- staging.json
- dev.json

Then depending on what configuration file you want to use, you can directly run the command:

```js
npx cypress run --config-file staging.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up `cypress.env.nonprod.json` and `cypress.env.prod.json` for envrionment-specific, and `cypress.env.json` for common variables.

In `cypress/support/index.js` add

```js
const env = Cypress.env()  // configured env from common cypress.env.json + command line

if (env.nonprod) {         // has nonprod environment been set?
  const addEnv = require('cypress.env.nonprod.json')
  const merged = {...env, ...addEnv}
  Cypress.env(merged)      
}

if (env.prod) {         // has prod environment been set?
  const addEnv = require('cypress.env.prod.json')
  const merged = {...env, ...addEnv}
  Cypress.env(merged)      
}
```

Run from command line (or set up script)

```js
npx cypress run --env nonprod=true
```

This allows "stacking" where multiple files can be merged

```js
npx cypress run --env nonprod=true,prod=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cypress/plugins.index.js` to merge named environment variable file

```js
// plugins/index.js

module.exports = (on, config) => {

  if (config.env.environment) {
    const envars = require(`cypress.env.${config.env.environment}.json`
    config.env = {
      ...config.env,
      ...envars
    }
  }

  return config
}
```

To add `cypress.env.nonprod.json` to base config (cypress.json)

```js
npx cypress run --env environment=nonprod
```